# SugarCRM Legacy SOAP API does not return any error if ID is not present in update operation, but V10 API return Error

Tags: java, rest, api, sugarcrm

I am trying to update SugarCRM Account object using ID, but the record of the ID is not present on SugarCRM site, but still its returning success, instead of error regarding ID or record not available.i am using API version 4 (REST and SOAP).POST **https://magicsoft.sugaropencloud.eu/service/v4_1/rest.php HTTP/1.1** of this url it's giving success even record not present. is the problem with API's?